# Why is my JVM application intermittently resolving hostnames as if they were not absolute?

Tags: java, linux, dns, jvm

A few weeks ago I started seeing intermittent UnknownHostExceptions logged by a JVM application running on ec2 Centos boxes.  dnstop shows error frequencies between 1% and 10%.  The errors seem to be triggered by a load that is unusual for this particular application, though not unusual (in any way that I can see) compared to other smoothly-running applications we have deployed.

tcpdump reveals that the NXDomain responses from the DNS server are accurate:  the errors are caused by the application intermittently resolving hostnames as if they were not absolute.  For example, when connecting to www.example.com, the application normally sends a DNS query to learn the address of www.example.com.  These queries succeed.  Intermittently, between 1% and 10% of the time, the application attempts to resolve www.example.com.foo.mycompany.com instead, where foo.mycompany.com is the sole entry in the search section of the /etc/resolv.conf on the boxes hosting the application.  When the application does this, the DNS server responds with NXDomain, and an UnknownHostException is thrown.  The application does not attempt to resolve the name any other way when this happens:  it makes a single DNS query and then throws the exception.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Why does it happen?  Is there a fix?  For the moment we seem to have fixed things by removing the search domain from resolv.conf, but it isn't a satisfactory solution.

More info for the curious:  The man page for resolv.conf indicates that a hostname should be resolved as a non-absolute hostname when the number of dots is less than a configurable threshold.  The default is 1, and it is not overridden on these boxes, which is why www.example.com (which has two dots) is usually resolved as an absolute hostname.  If I were to run "ssh bar", the ssh process would recognize bar as not being an absolute hostname, so it would consult the search path in /etc/resolv.conf and assume I was attempting to ssh to bar.foo.mycompany.com.  If I were to run "ssh bar.example.com", the ssh process would recognize the argument as an absolute hostname, and it would *not* try to resolve bar.example.com.foo.mycompany.com.

EDIT:  Output of java -version:

```
java version "1.6.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: you should add informations about your jvm (vendor, version for example).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why client thread is destroyed after it is executed only once? Java TCP sockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978451/why-client-thread-is-destroyed-after-it-is-executed-only-once-java-tcp-sockets)

Comment: The DNS client code caches results for a time.  You may only be seeing those lookups that were not available in the cache.